# Call Config::Load doesn't work in Fuelphp

Tags: fuelphp

I have a class in the path 'app/classes' called 'Helper.php'. And also I have a config file 'custom.php' in 'app/config'.

The problem is, when I call the config file, this return FALSE.

```
class Helper {    
  public static function actions_header ($ractive) {    
    return Config::load('custom');    
  }
}
```

The custom config file

```
return array(
  'sidebar_entities' => array (
    array(
      'name' => 'Dashboard',
      'icon' => 'icon-dashboard',
      'url'  => 'dashboard'
    ),
    array(
      'name' => 'Álbumes',
      'icon' => 'icon-music',
      'url'  => 'albums'
    )
  )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need something like this:

// load the config

Config::load('custom', true); // true - so you load the config to group 'custom'

// return array of items

return Config::get('custom');

I have not tested this, but something like this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to repeat the same code and everything works fine for me. FuelPHP 1.7.

Answer (score 0):

Up until 2012-08-28, load() only returned the loaded data on the initial call. If you called load() and the file is already loaded, it returned false. Since then, it will not load the file again, but return what is already loaded.

So the question is: how old is the version of Fuel you are using? Given the date of the change, that would be < 1.3, which is very old...

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this issue as well. I run the following code. (I am running Fuel 1.6)

```
Config::load('config_file_name') //returns config array
Config::load('config_file_name') //returns false
```

Then I run the following to load a sub array of the config file.

```
Config::get('config_file_name.attr') //returns nothing
```

Turns out I just didn't understand the fuel documentation. Thanks @huglester, your answer made it all make sense for some reason.

The documentation says:

```
// This merges the "custom" config file in with the root config.
Config::load('custom');

// This loads the "custom" config file in a group named "custom".
Config::load('custom', true);
```

So, when you run `Config::load('config_file_name')`, you can access the config sub arrays by using `Config::get('attr')`. This is because the 'config_file_name' is merged with the root config.

If you want to use `Config::get('config_file_name.attr')`, then you need to load the config file using `Config::load('config_file_name', true)`